Polyfill Supply Chain Attack Malicious Code Execution (CVE-2024-38526)
How can I check if any of our applications or systems in my enterprise contains JavaScript code obtained from the polyfill[.]io domain ?
Is there any file I can search for it using a PowerShell script or something else to help me to detect ?

It depends a bit on the setup of your enterprise. How many servers are you talking about? tens? thousands? What do they look like? Which OS, web server, etc. The basic idea is that none of your sites should load anything from the polyfill.io domain, or use anything that was downloaded from there, because that domain shouldn't be trusted.

If your codebase is in GitHub, dependabot from GHAS should flag it

If you have less number of sites to check and you check the technologies with builtwith from the browser.

Good suggestion, but https://builtwith.com wasn't made for this purpose and your answer looks more like a comment than an answer.
